# GridLayout(3,3,10,10) displays only 2 columns instead of 3

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, grid-layout

I am having difficulty getting the `GridLayout` to work. I used `GridLayout(3,3,10,10)`, but the result only shows 2 columns instead of 3.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Bunch extends JFrame {
    JButton m=new JButton("M");
    JButton c=new JButton("C");
    JButton g=new JButton("G");
    JButton j=new JButton("J");
    JButton k=new JButton("K");
    JButton h=new JButton("H");

    public Bunch() {
        super("Bunch");
        setSize(260,260);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel pane=new JPanel();
        GridLayout family=new GridLayout(3,3,10,10;
        pane.setLayout(family);
        pane.add(m);
        pane.add(c);
        pane.add(g);
        pane.add(j);
        pane.add(k);
        pane.add(h);
        add(pane);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        Bunch frame=new Bunch();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you miss the parentheses in: GridLayout family=new GridLayout(3,3,10,10;

Answer (score 3):

It's normal, you add 6 components, but for 6 components you need only 2 columns. You need to add 3 more components for 3 columns or change your GridLayout to : `GridLayout(2,3,10,10)`

Comment: Was going to say this. +1 to you sir!